# Шаблон для однонаправленного списка (стека)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть обыкновенный однонаправленный список c функцией добавления элемента в начало и вывода списка:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*template<typename T> */struct Link{
    /*T*/int data;  
    Link* next; 
};
class List{
    Link* first;
public:
    List() :first(NULL){}
    ~List(){        
        Link *current = first;
        while (current != NULL){
            Link* temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        cerr << "Deleted" << endl;
    }
    void add(int d){        //добавление в начало
        Link* newlink = new Link;
        newlink->data = d;
        newlink->next = first;
        first = newlink;
    }
    void show(){
        Link* current = first;
        while (current){
            cout << current->data << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    List LS;
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        LS.add(i);
    }

    LS.show();

    _gettch();
    return 0;
}
```

как добавить шаблон сюда? чтобы можно было вставлять любой тип данных:

```
template<typename T> struct Link{
    T data; 
    Link* next; 
};
```

Я знаю как это сделать просто с КЛАССОМ:

```
template <class T> class Stack{
    enum {MX=5};
    T st[MX];
    int top;
public:
    Stack();
    void push(T );
    T pop();
};
```

Но не получается обойти эту двойную вложенность: ставил `template<typename T>` перед классом и каждым его методом. Менял `int d` на `T d`... Даже при создании `List LS;`(или `List<int> LS;`) подчеркивает красным и выводит ошибку.

Comment: вложите struct Link внутрь класса списка.

Comment: Просто интересно - вы именно так и пишете? `template<typedef T>`? не `template<typename T>`?... :)

Comment: @KoVadim помогло, спасибо. А как быть с вариантом через 'Link<T>* current '. Чуть ниже переписал код. Но не до конца отлаживается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакой двойной вложенности, просто если у Вас есть шаблонный класс `Link`, то класс, его содержащий, должен либо использовать только одну версию(конкретную) этого `Link`, либо же тоже быть шаблонным.

```
template<typename T> 
struct Link{
    T* data;  
    Link* next; 
};

template<typename T> 
class List{
    Link<T>* first;
public:
    List() :first(nullptr){}
    ~List(){        
        Link<T> *current = first;
        while (current != nullptr){
            Link<T>* temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        cerr << "Deleted" << endl;
    }
    // и т.д. в том же ключе
};
```

Comment: исправил, спасибо. А как быть теперь? Переписал код ниже,

Comment: @JoraPetrov, может Вам книгу почитать, самую простейшую? `Link<T>* newlink = new Link<T>;`